# Distance calculation in RinSim 4.1.1

Tags: java, rinsim

I tried to compute the distance to a delivery location using a `RoadModel` based on a .dot file. However, the calculated distance using `Point.distance(currPos, destPos)` gives a result that does not seem to fit. I compared this with the distance from `MoveProgress` (`RoadModel.moveTo(...)`) and saw that the point distance is about a factor 100 more.

For example, when using the Taxi example from `rinsim-example-4.1.1.jar` with the following implementation of the `Taxi` class

```
class Taxi extends Vehicle implements SimulatorUser {

private RandomGenerator rng;

Taxi(Point startPosition, int capacity) {
    super(VehicleDTO.builder().capacity(capacity).startPosition(startPosition)
                    .speed(1000).build());
}

@Override
public void setSimulator(SimulatorAPI api) {
    rng = api.getRandomGenerator();
}

@Override
protected void tickImpl(TimeLapse time) {
    final RoadModel rm = getRoadModel();

    Point start = rm.getPosition(this);
    MoveProgress mp;

    if (rm.getDestination(this) == null) {
        mp = rm.moveTo(this, rm.getRandomPosition(rng), time);
    }

    if (rm.getPosition(this).equals(rm.getDestination(this)))
        mp = rm.moveTo(this, rm.getRandomPosition(rng), time);
    else
        mp = rm.moveTo(this, rm.getDestination(this), time);

    Point after = rm.getPosition(this);

    System.out.println("Travelled distance");
    System.out.println(mp.distance());
    System.out.println("Straight line distance");
    System.out.println(Point.distance(start, after));
}
```

then the travelled distance is around 0.277 whereas the calculated straight line distance is about 27.7. Is there a reason for the factor 100 difference or another way to get the distance between two points in the same measure as `MoveProgress`?

Comment: It looks like a bug, I'm investigating. I'll let you know as soon as I know more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the difference in distance as obtained by `Point.distance(..,..)` and `MoveProgress` is that the latter takes any available [ConnectionData](https://static.javadoc.io/com.github.rinde/rinsim-geom/4.1.1/com/github/rinde/rinsim/geom/ConnectionData.html) into account while the former computes the bird flight distance between two points (ignoring any connection related information).

It turns out that the graph that is used in the `TaxiExample` has many connections for which the connection length is overridden. It looks as if this length is off by a factor 100 as you mentioned, but it has to be investigated more thoroughly to see what would be the correct value.

For now, a workaround is to simply ignore all `ConnectionData`. Use the following code for parsing the graph:

```
final Graph<LengthData> originalGraph = 
  DotGraphIO.getLengthGraphIO().read(Paths.get("path/to/graph.dot"));

final Graph<LengthData> newGraph = new TableGraph<>();
for (final Connection<LengthData> conn : originalGraph.getConnections()) {
  newGraph.addConnection(conn.from(), conn.to());
}
```

This will construct a new graph without any connection data associated to any of the connections.

Comment: Works like a charm and also solved why my vehicle moved faster than it should!